# How to get XCode 6, LLVM compiler to check c function arguments

Tags: c, xcode

Does anyone know how to get the Apple LLVM compiler in Xcode 6 to warn if function arguments do not match prototypes?  With default settings, the following does not generate a warning:

```
void test(int *x)
{
    printf("%d",*x);
}

void caller()
{
    int x = 5;
    test(x);
}
```

I tried "require function prototypes" in settings, but that just complains when functions do not have a prototype distinct from the declaration.  The problem above occurs whether I have separate prototype or not.  It also seems not to care whether the number of arguments match the declaration or prototype.  Also, I tried -Wstrict-prototypes but that had no effect.  This almost seems like a bug.

Update:  I just tried this with a different Xcode project on a different Mac, and I get the warning as expected.  So, something is broken on that other system.  I would blame it on the project, but I saw the same behavior with 2 unrelated projects.  Both projects were created some years ago, and have been auto-upgraded through various iterations of Xcode, but that is true with the one that works.  The system with the problem is running Yosemite, while the one without a problem is running Mavericks.  Same Xcode 6.1.1.  The problematic system is not at hand right now, or else I would compare behavior of 2 brand new identical projects.

Comment: `-Wint-conversion` ?

Comment: `-Wall` has `-Wconversion` enabled by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it was simply misconfigured projects.  "suspicious implicit conversions" was set to No, which had the effect of setting Wno-int-conversion, which allows int <-> pointer conversions without warning.  I thought I had seen some other behavior that suggested it wasn't checking the declaration/prototype at all, so I was looking for settings related to that.  Looking at the compiler command line pointed out the issue.